# Inputting a file in R without setwd()

Tags: json, r, docker, setwd

I'm trying to input a text file into R using grep and using setwd() (I can use other methods, I'm not sure what, I'm only starting to learn R).

I'm writing a json template for a third-party server that runs a docker image as an env but currently there is a bug that can't change the working directory. Is there another way to get this file?

Comment: It's really hard for me to understand what you mean. Maybe you should create a small reproducible example of what you are trying to do and the expected output.

Comment: You can open files using their absolute or relative path.

Comment: Use file.path ti construct paths

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do something like this:

```
setwd('/tmp')
read.csv('hello.csv')
```

You can do without `setwd`:

```
read.csv('/tmp/hello.csv')
```